# TotalVirtualMemory returns unrealistic number for my application

Tags: c#, .net

My application is returning a very large number for TotalVirtualMemory. I instantiate a ComputerInfo() object and call TotalVirtualMemory and the value returned is ~130TB. Creating a basic project to test this seems to return the correct value: ~4GB. What could be causing this? My Code is below:

```
using System;  
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Virtual Memory: {test.GetTotalVirtualMemory()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Virtual Memory Readable: {test.GetTotalVirtualMemory() * (1.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0)}");
        }

        public ulong GetTotalVirtualMemory()
        {
            return new ComputerInfo().TotalVirtualMemory;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is so unrealistic about that value? Modern versions of Windows provide `128TiB` of address space for x64 applications.

Comment: What do you mean with "Creating a basic project to test this"?

Comment: Your "basic project" has the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox turned on.  Project > Properties > Build tab.  You would get 2GB on a 32-bit OS or when you set the Platform Target to x86.  The ~130 terabyte is truly virtual, you can't get the paging file to grow that large quickly enough.  Nor would you ever want to garbage-collect that much heap.  A 64-bit OS is going to be good enough for a while to come.

Comment: I think I may be confusing what TotalVirtualMemory is. My understanding of it is basically that it is a swap file for an application. Is it possible to find the total virtual memory available for a certain application rather than the total virtual memory available to the system?

Comment: You are probably looking for `var p = Process.GetCurrentProcess(); var mem = p.VirtualMemorySize64;p.Dispose()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4GB is only expected for 32 bit processes, the number you got is the expected number for 64 bit processes

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var test = new Program();
            Console.WriteLine($"Is 64 Bit Process: {Environment.Is64BitProcess}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Virtual Memory: {test.GetTotalVirtualMemory()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Total Virtual Memory Readable: {test.GetTotalVirtualMemory() * (1.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0 / 1024.0)}");
        }

        public ulong GetTotalVirtualMemory()
        {
            return new ComputerInfo().TotalVirtualMemory;
        }
    }
}
```

Change your "platform target" in the "project properties -> build tab", to be only run on x86 instead of being set to x64 or AnyCPU and you will see the 4GB number you expected.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK, C# compiler do not set *Large address space aware* bit when compiling x32 applications, thus it is likely only `2GiB` will be available in that case.

Comment: Ah I see. My understanding of TotalVirtualMemory was incorrect. Is it possible to check the total virtual memory available for a certain application? Surely Windows wouldn't let a single application take up 130TBs worth of swap space?

Comment: Yes it will, swap does not take up space in the swap file unless the memory gets faulted (accessed for the first time) then space is assigned to it in the swap file. Also there are things like Memory Mapped Files that don't ever go in to swap but do take up room in the virtual address space. See [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/943175/windows-says-ram-ran-out-while-there-is-still-4-gb-of-physical-memory-available/943185#943185) that goes in to very good detail about how virtual memory actually works.